# User and Account model - Whats the theory behind this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Today I've been reading the Rails Antipatterns book. There's a topic on page 25, where it speaks of two models: User and Account.

The reason? Some would say data separation / separation of concerns ([SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

The Account model should have stuff that isn't specific to the functionality of the user, but is related to their account.

So for example: personal information (first_name, last_name) go into the Account model while username/ email, password etc go into the User model.

Is this the common approach for most situations? I am trying to understand why there are two models involved. In most situations, shouldn't having a User model be enough? What is the benefit of having an Account model as well?

Comment: Depending on the relationships you define, an Account could potentially have many Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 2009 response to a similar question:
[REST API / DATA MODEL DESIGN - User , Account or Both Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785407/rest-api-data-model-design-user-account-or-both-models)

I can imagine where an account may have many users as kchau comments above and as discussed in the stackoverflow link above.   I can also conceive of a user has_many accounts example: I use QBO (Quickbooks online) and when I login I am presented with my 2 accounts for 2 different businesses I manage. I am the same user in either account.  Each account has separate payment details among other things.